# changing value of first column in a file using awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have a .csv file that has multiple columns and I wanted to change the value of the first column in the file to "positive" for all rows except when it is "negative"

So if I have the file

```
product,0 0,no way
brand,0 0 0,detergent
product,0 0 1,sugar
negative,0 0 1, sight
```

I want to make it

```
positive,0 0,no way
positive,0 0,detergent
positive,0 0 1,sugar
negative,0 0 1, sight
```

How can I accomplish this using awk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^negative,/!s/^[^,]*/positive/' file
```

If the first word is not `negative` change it to `positive`.

Answer (score 1):

this awk one-liner should help you:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '$1="positive"' file
```

since you tagged with `sed`:

```
sed 's/[^,]*/positive/' file
```

### update for OP's new requirement:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '$1="negative"==$1?$1:"positive"' file
```

or:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '"negative"==$1||$1="positive"' file
```

Comment: Kent, I just edited the question a bit looking at my data. Thanks !